# How to use Group by, Pivot_table, Stack & Unstack to reshape Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, reshape

I have a Dataframe that looks like:
[image]

I want to change it to look like:
[image]

I KNOW this is easy to do with groupby &/or pivot_table &/or stack - I just can't seem to get it off base one.  My notes haven't quite worked for telling me how to do this.  I thought I got close with the pivot_table from the pandas docs - but couldn't get it to do even one level - let alone 2.  As I'm not trying to aggregate anything.  My notes were all around doing aggregations...

Any suggestions gratefully accepted

code to create 1st dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CPC_qtr_root': {13: 0.13493790567404607,
  14: 0.14353736611331172,
  15: 0.10359919568913414,
  16: 0.077153346715340618,
  17: 0.066759430932458397,
  39: 0.12067193385680651,
  40: 0.049033000970486448,
  41: 0.047640864406214359,
  42: 0.040086869604689483,
  43: 0.038795815932666726,
  100: 0.11017683494905577,
  101: 0.15510499735697988,
  102: 0.16478351543691827,
  103: 0.091894700285988867,
  104: 0.0359603120618152},
 'Country': {13: u'Afghanistan',
  14: u'Afghanistan',
  15: u'Afghanistan',
  16: u'Afghanistan',
  17: u'Afghanistan',
  39: u'Albania',
  40: u'Albania',
  41: u'Albania',
  42: u'Albania',
  43: u'Albania',
  100: u'Angola',
  101: u'Angola',
  102: u'Angola',
  103: u'Angola',
  104: u'Angola'},
 'IncomeLevel': {13: 'Lower Income',
  14: 'Lower Income',
  15: 'Lower Income',
  16: 'Lower Income',
  17: 'Lower Income',
  39: 'Upper Middle Income',
  40: 'Upper Middle Income',
  41: 'Upper Middle Income',
  42: 'Upper Middle Income',
  43: 'Upper Middle Income',
  100: 'Lower Middle Income',
  101: 'Lower Middle Income',
  102: 'Lower Middle Income',
  103: 'Lower Middle Income',
  104: 'Lower Middle Income'},
 'Rate': {13: 27.0,
  14: 37.0,
  15: 35.0,
  16: 39.0,
  17: 48.0,
  39: 95.0,
  40: 95.0,
  41: 96.0,
  42: 93.0,
  43: 96.0,
  100: 36.0,
  101: 65.0,
  102: 66.0,
  103: 52.0,
  104: 52.0},
 'Year': {13: 2000,
  14: 2001,
  15: 2002,
  16: 2003,
  17: 2004,
  39: 2000,
  40: 2001,
  41: 2002,
  42: 2003,
  43: 2004,
  100: 2000,
  101: 2001,
  102: 2002,
  103: 2003,
  104: 2004}})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df3 = df2.set_index(['Year','Country']).stack().unstack(1)
print (df3)
Country             Afghanistan              Albania               Angola
Year                                                                     
2000 CPC_qtr_root      0.134938             0.120672             0.110177
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    27                   95                   36
2001 CPC_qtr_root      0.143537             0.049033             0.155105
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    37                   95                   65
2002 CPC_qtr_root      0.103599            0.0476409             0.164784
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    35                   96                   66
2003 CPC_qtr_root     0.0771533            0.0400869            0.0918947
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    39                   93                   52
2004 CPC_qtr_root     0.0667594            0.0387958            0.0359603
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    48                   96                   52
```

Get mixed types:

```
print (df3.head().applymap(type))
Country                Afghanistan          Albania           Angola
Year                                                                
2000 CPC_qtr_root  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
     IncomeLevel     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
     Rate          <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
2001 CPC_qtr_root  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
     IncomeLevel     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert those strings that look like numbers back to numbers?

Comment: It seems to be handling the values as mixed type - but the Year is doing something odd. I am using it as the x axis in a plot and instead of using the year it is converting them and adding some kind of power in the axis label.  Anyways - you have given me a great answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can first melt your dataframe from wide to long, using `Year` and `Country` as IDs and `IncomeLevel`, `CPC_qtr_root`, and `Rate` as values:

```
df3 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['Year', 'Country'], value_vars=['IncomeLevel', 'CPC_qtr_root', 'Rate'])
```

Then you can pivot your table:

```
pd.pivot_table(df3, index = ['Year', 'variable'], 
                columns = 'Country',
                values = 'value',
                aggfunc = np.sum,
                fill_value = 0)
```

This returns:

```
Country             Afghanistan              Albania               Angola
Year variable                                                            
2000 CPC_qtr_root      0.134938             0.120672             0.110177
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    27                   95                   36
2001 CPC_qtr_root      0.143537             0.049033             0.155105
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    37                   95                   65
2002 CPC_qtr_root      0.103599            0.0476409             0.164784
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    35                   96                   66
2003 CPC_qtr_root     0.0771533            0.0400869            0.0918947
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    39                   93                   52
2004 CPC_qtr_root     0.0667594            0.0387958            0.0359603
     IncomeLevel   Lower Income  Upper Middle Income  Lower Middle Income
     Rate                    48                   96                   52
```